# Extracting Data from Website that uses _doPostBack (JavaScript) Programmatically (C#)

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, dopostback, data-extraction

I am trying to extract data from a website using C#. The problem I am facing is that the website implements JavaScript (i.e., _doPostBack method) to navigate between the pages. In other word, the page includes numeric buttons (1, 2, 3, 4, ...) similar to the Google page results. When you press any numeric buttons, the button will call a function called "_doPostBack" to navigate between the result pages. I searched inside a page's script of the website (including _doPostBack method), but I could not find any link used to retrieve data. Besides, I looked inside the JavaScript files with no indication to any link. Please, what should I do?

Thank you

Comment: I think the only way to do that is to simulate that navigation (the HTTP POST action) manually from C# code. I would be glad to learn if there is a way.